# KB972455 Windows Server Update Services 3.0 SP2

Tags: wsus, windows-sbs

My Small Business Server 2003 failed to install this update SP2 for WSUS3.0. The update is not available for rollback. WSUS 3.0 is not to be found in my software configscreen or startup menu. Some files have been deleted from the hard drive and last but not least. The service will not run and .NET runtime errors keep flooding my logs.

Question. How to remove an update or program which is not listed in add/remove software anymore. Since the update it fails to run WSUS.

Event-id: 0
Category: none
Source: .NET Runtime
ERROR:

This error keeps flooding my logs. I am hesitant to roll back to a system restore point since exchange is running on the same disks.... :)

Comment: What was the .NET Runtime Error (Stack Trace)?

Comment: None given in logging... :( I am trying to install WSUS again! ;( Just to be able to remove it later.... sigh

Comment: Is it a x86 or x64 core?

Answer (score 1):

What I would do is to uninstall the WSUS SP2 and check if this fix the issue. If not...

Backup all of your email on exchange and everything that could be business critical and perform a system restore. Then, restore the exchange backups and try to update the WSUS SP1 from this address:

[http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?...](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=F87B4C5E-4161-48AF-9FF8-A96993C688DF&displaylang=en)

That's what I'd try...

Comment: I cannot uninstall it. It disapeared from my software list and has only left traces of it to be found. In the registry and some files / services... .NET RUNTIME keeps comming back every hour with same empty error.